# ng generate store AppState --root --module app.module.ts error

Tags: angular, ngrx, store

I have an error when I execute the command below.

ng generate store AppState --root --module app.module.ts

I'm getting this error

> Cannot read property 'root' of undefined

ngrx/store packages era the last that I installed.

My packages.json is:

```json
    {
  "name": "hrm-crm-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-testing": "ng build -c testing",
    "deploy-testing": "npm run build-testing && copy src\\app.test.yaml dist\\app\\app.yaml && gcloud app deploy dist\\app\\app.yaml"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.0",
    "@auth0/auth0-angular": "^1.3.1",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^10.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^10.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^10.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^11.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^10.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **@ngrx/schematics** command prefix to make it work. While installing @ngrx/schematics it asks for default collection. As you don't have default collection so you can use below command to generate store.

```js
ng generate @ngrx/schematics:store AppState --root --module app.module.ts
```

Above command works fine for Angular 10+ version.